# how do i check if normalized css is working in angularjs or not?

Tags: css, angularjs, styles, denormalized

How do i check if normalized css is working in Angular.js or not after importing normalized.css in the style.css file. After I click on the import i.e. Cntrl + click it says cant find the file.

The things i did to include normalize.css is 
1) `npm install --save normalize.css`
2) @import '~normalize.css'; in my style.css file
3) Under styles added `"../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css"` in my angular.json file.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the styles applied to the html tag and see if the following two are applied:

```
line-height: 1.15;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

You can check other styles that are applied by looking at the normalize.css file inside the package files on Github here: [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css)

Comment: The line-height: 1.15 is correct, but I don't see the -webkit-text part.  Anyway, thanks, this helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

try to type ul and li tags into html file  .. If displayed without dots, we conclude that this file works. also I think if we have written h1,h2,h3 they will have same size

Comment: By dots do you mean bullets? If yes its not working.
The things i did to include normalize.css is 
1) npm install --save normalize.css
2) @import '~normalize.css'; in my style.css file
3) Under styles added "../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css" in my angular.json file.

Comment: yes i mean bullets .. try to type h2 and h4 and check its sizes ..
and check  main.js file into your frame work if its contain normalize file or not

Comment: hi, by using h2 and h4 i see the sizes are different. Also my normalize.css file is under node_modules folder which i am importing in my style.css file by writing @ import '~normalize.css'; and i believe this should look into node_modules folder for normalize.css file right? But when i click on @import '~normalize.css'; it shows the message cant find the file. And in the error i see that it is searching normalize.css file inside src folder instead of node_modules folder. Another query> Is it fine if i create an normalize.css file manually and add all css and import them into style.css?

Comment: The normalize.css package does not remove the dots in front of "li" items, so this check is not valid. See my answer for a valid check